# Can telegraf store metrics data on the local system during network outages and later forward it?

Tags: telegraf

We have IoT devices which are mostly connected well to the internet, but there is a possibility that the network goes down. For this case, the device itself will do the right thing (while it cannot be actively controlled any more). We would still like to get metrics data for the time in which the network is down.

It means a device-local telegraf would need to collect the metrics data, store it and check on the network connection. If the network is up (again), then forward to a influxDB for example.

Is it possible to achieve this scenario with Telegraf/InfluxDB or prometheus?

Answer (score 4):

Telegraf can not store metrics on the local drive in the case of a failure. However, in can buffer unsuccessfully sent metrics (I believe in RAM) and flush the buffer on the successful write. Take a look at `metric_buffer_limit` option in Telegraf config:

```
# Configuration for telegraf agent
[agent]
  ## For failed writes, telegraf will cache metric_buffer_limit metrics for each
  ## output, and will flush this buffer on a successful write. Oldest metrics
  ## are dropped first when this buffer fills.
  ## This buffer only fills when writes fail to output plugin(s).
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
```

This way, as far as you don't overflow this buffer, metrics collected while InfluxDB is down will still be preserved and resent later.

Edit: you can track a similar feature request [here](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/802).

Comment: thx, great answer. This is going in the right direction, but buffering in RAM is not an option for us. We need a "buffer to disk in case of failure" option, which currently does not yet exist. Woudl be great to see this in the future.